# Good place for questions about SE's TOS

Tags: discussion, scope

If I have a question about legal details of the SE Terms of Service, is it better to ask on MSE, or is this site (also) an appropriate place to ask?

Comment: Your relevant question (that's currently on MSE): [Does linked content count as "Subscriber Content" under the TOS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390800/335251)

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a question about legal details of the SE Terms of Service, is it better to ask on MSE, or is this site (also) an appropriate place to ask?

The most appropriate place to ask is neither MSE nor Law Meta (i.e., "this site"), but the Law site.

SE Meta sites are for issues regarding how the underlying (i.e., subject matter) sites are run, or how users want them to run. The inquiry might involve the site's TOS, but the issues brought up on Meta sites are mostly of an operational nature and require no legal expertise.

By contrast, a question that entails a deeper assessment of legal details or legal ramifications of a product's TOS pertains to Law SE. The coincidence that the product at issue happens to be an SE site is irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

### Yes

Comment: It's not explicitly clear what your "Yes" is responding to. "is it better to ask on MSE, or is this site (also) an appropriate place to ask?" is an "either or" question, not a "yes/no" question.